# Can't inject HTML into body without loosing everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to call a JS function to append a few divs into the `body`

When I do `getElementById`, I can't add to `body`, so this is usually basically.

```
document.getElementById('advertisingBrandValues').innerHTML = "Test"
```

And when I do

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Test"
```

**ALL** the HTML is replaced with that one element. I need to **add** new elements to the body, not replace the whole thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the bottom:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "Test"
```

To add to the top:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Test" + document.body.innerHTML
```